# Cannot assign "": "" must be a '' instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make a registration key in the UserModel where the key field in the registration form is a foreign key to another model called RegistrationKey. I have made two posts about this topic earlier without any success, however has a few things changed in my code which makes those previous posts irrelevant. In the form field, the field for the key is a CharField as I can not display the keys for the users due to safety.

These are the two previous posts:
[Save user input which is a string as object in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71413813/save-user-input-which-is-a-string-as-object-in-db) ,
[Textinput with ModelChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429997/textinput-with-modelchoicefield)

These are my two models.

```
class RegistrationKey(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key


class User(AbstractUser):
    key = models.ForeignKey(RegistrationKey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Since my latest posts have I created a class based view, which looks like this:

```
class RegisterPage(CreateView):
    form_class = MyUserCreationForm


  def form_valid(self, form):
        key = form.cleaned_data['key']
        try:
            keyobject = RegistrationKey.objects.get(key=key)
            form.instance.key = keyobject
            return super().form_valid(form)
        except RegistrationKey.DoesNotExist:
            form.add_error('key', 'error')
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

When I try and pass in the value Admin which is an object in the RegistrationKey model I get the following error:
'Cannot assign "'Admin'": "User.key" must be a "RegistrationKey" instance.'
I don't know how to solve this, how can this string that the user inputs be assigned to the db?

**Edit**
Here are my form

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    key = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Key'}), label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}), label='')



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('key', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
        self.fields['password1'].label=''

        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label=''
        
        for fieldname in ['password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None
```

Comment: Share your `MyUserCreationForm`. The problem occurs when it tries to save that form.

Comment: Added the form now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better move the logic to obtain the item to the form, where it belongs. So with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    # …

    def clean_key(self):
        key = self.cleaned_data['key']
        try:
            return RegistrationKey.objects.get(key=key)
        except RegistrationKey.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('The key is not valid.')
```

That should be sufficient. You should not override the `.form_valid(…)` method.